# EACCES (Permission denied) on Android 11 And targetApi30

Tags: android

targetApi 30
do not request READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
use SAF api to get a uri like this:
"content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document%3"
and parse the uri like this:

this error::onFailure: /storage/emulated/0/Download/Vaccinatio.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: Please try to write a readable post. Tell what you are doing and what goes wrong.

Comment: EACCES (Permission denied) on Android 11 And targetApi30